# Creating a proplist from a set of nested records

Tags: erlang

I'm having trouble working out how to turn my structure of nested records to / from a proplist. I can turn individual records into a proplist with:

```
lists:zip(record_info(fields,typea), tl(tuple_to_list(Atypea))).
```

but this obviously falls over when the structure of the record contains lists of other records like so:

```
-record(typec, {
  id = 0,
  name = <<"typec">>,
 })

-record(typeb, {
  id = 0,
  name = <<"typeb">>,
  typec_list = [],
 }).

-record(typea, {
  id = 0,
  name = <<"typea">>,
  typec_list = [],
  typeb_list = [],
 }).
```

Any idea how I can achieve this, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could work:

```
to_proplist(C = #typec{}) -> lists:zip(record_info(fields, typec), tl(tuple_to_list(C)));
to_proplist(B = #typeb{}) ->
    B1 = B#typeb{typec_list = [to_proplist(C) || C <- B#typeb.typec_list]},
    lists:zip(record_info(fields, typeb), tl(tuple_to_list(B1)));
to_proplist(A = #typea{}) ->
    A1 = A#typea{typec_list = [to_proplist(C) || C <- A#typea.typec_list]},
    A2 = A1#typea{typeb_list = [to_proplist(B) || B <- A1#typea.typeb_list]},
    lists:zip(record_info(fields, typea), tl(tuple_to_list(A2))).
```

If you want to save the hassle of extending this for every involved type, I have just found this [runtime record_info](https://github.com/okeuday/record_info_runtime), however I haven't tried it yet.

Comment: Thank you, that works perfectly, I dont think ill need to use the runtime_record_info module you linked, but its nice to know that it exists!

Answer (score 2):

Variation of the solution given by filmor is as below

```
to_proplist(Record) ->
    to_proplist(Record,[]).


to_proplist(Type = #typea{}, []) ->
    lists:zip(record_info(fields, typea), to_list(Type));

to_proplist(Type = #typeb{}, []) ->
    lists:zip(record_info(fields, typeb), to_list(Type));

to_proplist(Type = #typec{}, []) ->
    lists:zip(record_info(fields, typec), to_list(Type));

to_proplist([NotAType | Rest], Res) ->
    to_proplist(Rest, [to_proplist(NotAType,[])| Res]);

to_proplist([], Res) ->
    lists:reverse(Res);

to_proplist(Val, []) ->
    Val.


to_list(Type) ->
    [to_proplist(L,[]) || L <- tl(tuple_to_list(Type))].
```

This will work for all combinations of the records. Only by adding a case clause additional records can be supported. Example:

```
to_proplist(Type = #typed{}, []) ->
        lists:zip(record_info(fields, typed), to_list(Type));
```